# undefined reference to `CommonAPI::SomeIP::Message::createErrorResponseMessage

Tags: ubuntu, c++11, vsomeip

The project set up was working fine in another system with same set of libraries and source code. I have checked if all the dependent libraries required are available in /usr/bin. The libraries use boost which is available in /usr/local/lib.

Please provide the solution if known or suggestion on how to further debug this situation, what are the configurations to be checked?

The project should build the exe using the libraries available in usr/lib.

error: undefined reference to `CommonAPI::SomeIP::Message::createErrorResponseMessage(vsomeip_v3::return_code_e) const' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status